# when i log in to my Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS it takes me immediately back to my log in screen

Tags: 12.04, login

When i log in to my Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS it takes me immediately back to my log in screen. This behavior began when I pressed the power button during installation of updates (to a new version of Ubuntu) somewhere around June or July of this year. If I type the wrong password it says "incorrect login". If I type the correct password, it goes black for a second then comes back to the log in page again. The log in page looks completely different than it used to under Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS. When I press    and then log in it just says incorrect login over and over again no matter what.

Answer (score 0):

Press `Ctrl-Alt-F1` in login screen to switch to fallback console. There, type

```
ping www.ya.ru
```

to check if you have Internet. If you do not, and do not know how to fix it, better reinstall. If yes, type

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

to try autofixing updates. Then type

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

then, may be, you will have to flush your user prefrences.

```
mkdir ~/oldsettings
mv ~/.* oldsettings/
```

Comment: When I press Ctrl-Alt-F1 it takes me to that black & white login console that looks like a command shell that takes up the entire screen. Once their typing ping does nothing. It acts like I'm typing in my login information incorrectly. I think maybe I'm typing ping in the wrong place or not going to the screen you're trying to tell me to go to. Does that make sense?